# Find if two numbers are linked by a greatest common divisor

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

Two numbers $x,y$ are 'connected' if $gcd(x,y)>g$. Here $gcd$ is the greatest common divisor. A path exists between two numbers $x,y$ if given $g$ and $n$ there is a sequence of numbers that connect $x$ to $y$ such that all numbers along the path are less than or equal to $n$.

How do you find if there exists a path between two numbers and if this needs to be repeated for multiple pairs of numbers would it be more optimal to first find all existing paths.

I've tried a basic approach of breadth-first search, where each query between two numbers involves calculating $gcd(x,y)>g$. However, this is quite laborious and want to see if there is a more optimal solution.

As a simple example to motivate the problem, let $x=10, y=30, z=18$. Assume $g>4$ and $n=50$. Then $x$ and $z$ are not directly connected but there is a path connecting $x$ to $y$ and from $y$ to $z$.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: We're a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question in the body of your post.  Also, we have strict quality standards.  Please tell us what approaches you've considered and why you rejected them.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  We're not looking for questions that are just the statement of an exercise-style task and a request for us to solve it.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: If you need to compute $\gcd$ of many numbers, you can create a table created using the recurrence $\gcd(x+y,y)=\gcd(x,y)$, $\gcd(x,y)=\gcd(y,x)$, $\gcd(x,x)=x$ and perhaps also $\gcd(x,1)=1$.

Comment: @plop is the suggestion here than for any given pair of numbers there's a look up? What if n is large, will the cost of this table outweigh actually calculating gcd() for any pair of numbers?

Comment: @TWhite The intension of my comment was only to tell you a general strategy that can be used when one needs GCDs of many pairs of numbers in a range. I haven't thought your specific problem.

Comment: How many numbers ? Magnitude of the numbers ?

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting problem. First of all, calculating directly the gcd between two numbers is clearly the fastest way to decide if they are connected. But as you noticed, quite unefficient for your problem.

A solution is to use prime factorization. Let's denote $P(z)$ the multiset prime factorization of a number $z$. Thus, you note that $gcd(x, y) = P(x) \cap P(y)$.
Once you have the prime factorization $P(x_0)$ of a number $x_0$, you may compute all sub-multisets (there are $2^k$ for $k$ primes values), and if the product $p$ of any sub-multiset is above $g$, any multiple of $p$ lesser than $n$ is connectected to $x_0$. Also note that all these multiples are a clique.

In fact, to generate all the connected numbers, you are only interested by "irreductible" sub-multisets. By irreductible, I mean that removing any (the smallest) prime factor would make the product lesser than $n$. Indeed, a reductible sub-multiset is already a multiple of an irreductible one and would generate no new connection. This may help to prune the loop on all sub-multisets of $x_0$.

Let's take a small example: $n = 100$, $g=10$, $x_0=60$.

$P(x_0) = \{2, 2, 3, 5\}$. The irreductible sub-multisets above $g$ are:

- $P(12) = \{2, 2, 3\}$ => generating connections to $12 \times [1, 8]$
- $P(15) = \{3, 5\}$ => generating connections to $15 \times [1, 6]$
- $P(20) = \{2, 2, 5\}$ => generating connections to $20 \times [1, 5]$

Thus, we may generate the exhaustive list of the numbers conneted to $x_0$: $12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 96, 15, 30, 45, 75, 90, 20, 40, 80, 100$.

Also note that by construction you already have partially the prime factorization of all these numbers.

In your question, it is quite unclear of what may be the limits of ($n$, $g$). Or if your several ($x$, $y$) share the same ($n$, $g$). What I discussed until now is the fastest way I found to explore the graph of connections. But for very high ($n$, $g$), it may be unconvenient to list explicitely all connections of a number. If you do a BFS/DFS, an important point is that there is no point to explore again the clique of an irreductible multiset. In fact, I think I would try to do the BFS/DFS on the graph of these irreductible multiset instead of the graph of the number values.

Also remember that it may exist no path between $x$ and $y$. For example with $g = 20$ and $n = 80$, one may identify some connected components:

- $\{31, 62\}$
- $\{35, 70\}$
- $\{21, 42, 63\}$
- $\{25, 50, 75\}$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. To clarify, $(n,g)$ are fixed but you don't know ahead of time what they are. So for a given set of (x,y), $n$ and $g$ are constant. Also, in your example list of numbers connected to $x_0=60$, $12$ cannot be a connection because it cannot have a divisor equal to or larger than $g=10$.

Comment: gcd(60, 12) = 12 as $60 = 12\times5$... Are we talking about the same "greater common divisor" ?

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, whenever you check successfully that x and y are connected, you have found a divisor > g of x and of y. You can record this and may be able to use it when you look for gcd(y, z).

If g is large then using Euclid’s algorithm but stopping when you know that gcd(x, y) <= g might make things quicker. For example if g=100, and Euclid showed you that gcd(x,y) = gcd (3517, 99) you don’t need to calculate the gcd at all. If g is close to n you may be able to do more: Say g >= n/3 and x <= n, then gcd(x, y) > g can only be true gcd = x or gcd = x/2.

But most savings can be had by having a good algorithm for finding a path from a to b, and breadth first isn’t it. Assume you have a trillion points, breadth first means you will examine more than half of all reachable points on average. Start your search from both ends and rely on the birthday paradox.

Comment: Interesting observations, and definitely agree that BFS isn't optimal here. Would memoizing gcd calculations here be helpful?

Comment: Gcd(n,m) only takes O(log(max(n,m))), that’s like rather small. A trivial implementation for N numbers could tak O(N^2) gcds, reducing that has much more potential. Plus there is the possibility that you’d need to memorise N^2 gcds, which you can’t.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn’t calculating gcd’s, your problem is the number of pairs you need to examine. If your algorithm isn’t clever then given some x, you’ll have to examine all y whether they are connected. This will take O(n) for each x.

Throw out all x > n and x <= g first. If one of your numbers is less than g then they cannot be linked. If their gcd is ≥ g then they are already linked. Factorise each x. Find all prime factors p with the property “x has a factor > g consisting of prime factors <= p only”. Example: x = $13*11*3*2$, g=7. p=13,11. If x is connected to y, then y must have a prime factor 13 or 11. If g=70 then p=13: x cannot be connected to any number that isn’t divisible by 13 (and such a number needs some smaller prime factors as well).

For each prime p make a list of all x with such a factor. Now you know that only numbers on the same list can be connected. And obviously if p > g then all pairs of numbers in the list are connected.

This is all done in k log n where k is the count of your numbers. Finding all numbers connected to some x should then be a lot quicker.

And then follow my algorithm for making an algorithm fast: implement something. Make it run. Figure out what it actually does. Figure out if it does unnecessary work or if it does necessary work too slowly. Make it faster and repeat.

PS. There are other things that you can do to simplify the problem. For example, if a ≤ n is a multiple of b, then you don't need b in the chain at all. If a is the only number containing some prime factor p then you can remove that factor from a.

With many numbers given, a solution is likely to exist. For example, if g = 2 then connecting both x and y to some (different) even number is enough. If g = 2 or g = 3 then connecting both x and y to a multiple of three is enough, and so on. This may give you a solution quickly. If g = 2 and there are two multiples of six, then all even numbers and all multiples of three are linked to each other, so if either x or y are connected to a multiple of 2 or 3, they are linked. So there are plenty of cases where you find links quickly.

Comment: I think this is close. Though need some clarifications. One thing I want to point out, and which I'll update the original question with, is that even if two numbers are not directly connected there can still exist a path between the two numbers. An example, $x=10, y=30, z=18$. Lets assume $g>4$ and $n=50$. Then $x$ and $z$ are not directly connected but there is a path connecting $x$ to $y$ and from $y$ to $z$.

Comment: @TWhite: That's fine. What my proposal does: Each number x can be directly connected to any number y. Instead with k log n effort I create lists so that every number x can only be directly connected to numbers y on the same list, and therefore needs comparing with much fewer elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check all pairwise relations (by explicit computation of the $\gcd$s) and fill a graph. Then compute the *transitive closure* of the graph, in a modified way (to account for the $n$ constraint).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure#Algorithms